# Running on localhost showing the html page name twice at url

Tags: html, angularjs

When I am trying to call an HTML page created under the root directory, it shows repeating the HTML file name twice at the url.

like:

```
http://localhost:8085/MyApp/CreateTask.html#/CreateTask.html
```

Can anyone tell me why it's happening ?

Any suggestion to prevent it.

Comment: Are you including the angular library twice?

Comment: Can you show your routing config?

Comment: @ pixelbits... No, I am including angular library only once for every html page.

Comment: @ MiTa... it's an angular js app. so, I am redirecting from a controller as like : location.href="CreateTask.html"; simply.

Comment: @ MiTa... Do I need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Is your link like that `<a href="#/CreateTask.html"></a>` in you calling page ?

Comment: No... Actually, I am calling it under a controller as like: location.href="CreateTask.html";

Comment: Try to use `location.href="./CreateTask.html"`

Comment: yeah I tried with this too. but didn't work (same problem with it).

Comment: What event cause the location to be modified ? A click on a button, the end of a loop ?

Comment: No, If I am trying to access directly on the URL. like: http://localhost:8085/MyApp/CreateTask.html That time also it's repeating twice and the URL modifies as http://localhost:8085/MyApp/CreateTask.html#/CreateTask.html

Comment: The '#' let suppose that `location.hash` is modified. I can't say anything more without any code, I'm sorry :/

Comment: @ Magador... I got the reason as it modifies the location.hash which actually appending the "#/PAGE_NAME" to it. How to resolute it ?